# Split list into 2d array

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, 2d

Hey I would like to split this list
['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']
into a 2d array for each character
so that it looks like this:
[['H', '-', V', 'C', G'], ['E','I, 'O','S], [and so on]]
I would really appreciate any help :)## Heading ##

Comment: Post your code first. Also research cause this is already solved

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to achieve this:

```
list1 = ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']

[list(x) for x in list1]
```

which will result in:

```
[['H', '-', 'V', 'C', 'G'],
['E', 'I', 'E', 'O', 'S'],
['L', '-', '-', 'D', '-'],
['L', 'L', 'E', 'I', '-'],
['O', 'O', 'N', 'N']]
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Next time try/search a bit longer to find a solution for yourself...

```
list = ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']
list2 = []
for string in list:
    list2.append([char for char in string])
print(list2)
list2 = [['H', '-', 'V', 'C', 'G'],
         ['E', 'I', 'E', 'O', 'S'], 
         ['L', '-', '-', 'D', '-'],
         ['L', 'L', 'E', 'I', '-'],
         ['O', 'O', 'N', 'N']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']
result = [list(element) for element in array]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list =  ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']
d_arr = []
for elem in my_list:
    inner = []
    for c in elem:
        inner.append(c)
    d_arr.append(inner)

print(d_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']
chars = [[ch for ch in word] for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
x = ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']

result = list(map(list, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map function with unpacking:

```
lines  = ['H-VCG', 'EIEOS', 'L--D-', 'LLEI-', 'OONN']
matrix = [*map(list,lines)]
```